# Python unconventional sorting algorithm

Tags: python, sorting

I have a task for uni that I need help with.
We were given a code that sorts lists correctly, but isn't "well thought out".
I cant find the logical flaw in how it works.
Somthing about the n loop using the result of the m loop.
Heres the code:

```
from random import randint
numbers = [randint(0,9) for x in range(20)] #random array for testing the sort
#sorting
for n in range(0, len(numbers)-1):
    for m in range(n + 1, len(numbers)):
        if numbers[n] > numbers[m]:
            a = numbers[n]
            numbers[n] = numbers[m]
            numbers[m] = a
#correctly sorted list
print(numbers)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: Of course you _"cant find the logical flaw in how it works"_! If it _sorts correctly_, as you wrote, then there is no _logical_ flaw in it. Maybe something else is not _"well thought out"_? I could think of a few things (this is not the best sorting algorithm ever), but your teacher probably expects something that was mentioned in class.

Comment: Insert a `print` statement or two to trace the operation.  Compare with a typical Bubble Sort?

Comment: @ringo - it's not a bubble sort, since it swaps non-adjacent elements and is not stable.

Comment: It is not clear by what is meant that the sort program is not "well thought out".

Comment: I tried the sort logic in C++ to speed things up. I tested 10^9 cases from {0,0,...,0,0} to {9,9,...,9,9} and it never failed, so there is no "logic flaw". It is not a stable sort, but since it is sorting numbers, this won't matter. There are faster algorithms, but if this is only being used for small arrays, it won't matter either.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

numbers = [randint(0,9) for x in range(20)]
n = len(numbers)

for i in range(n):
    for m in range(1, n-i):
        # change < to > to reverse the order
        if numbers[m-1] < numbers[m]:
            (numbers[m-1], numbers[m]) = (numbers[m], numbers[m-1])
print(numbers)
```

Untested! The n loop has been taken out of the equation but the variable is still referenced through the m loop. This way you are only using the value of m to sort the list without being dependent on comparison to n.

Comment: It's still a double loop, so same time complexity. Unlike's the questions sort, it sorts adjacent elements and is stable.

Comment: Yeah the polynomial time will be the same. For a simpler result you could just do numbers.sort() but I dont think that addresses the logical flaw the OP mentions

Answer (score -1):

This algorithm here is called `Bubble Sort`, in which course did you get this homework for? if its algorithms \ data structures than I can come up with an issue that may fit, the thing with bubble sort is that its `θ(n^2)`, which means, its best case (list already sorted) and the worst case (list is sorted backwards) have the exact same time complexity, you will always do `n^2` passes over the list, obviously you can come up with a better algorithm to reduce the time complexity. (view `Insertion Sort` or `Merge Sort` to learn more)

Comment: This isn't *quite* a bubble sort -- look at the mechanism to progress a number to its proper location.

Comment: The question's sort program swaps non-adjacent elements, and unlike bubble sort, it is not a stable sort.